# "Failed to add object with ID as the object already exists" but object not visible in playground test environment

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am testing my code on composer-playground. When I try to add a participant through a transaction, I receive an error "Failed to add object with ID --- as the object already exists".

However, when I go to 'test' section, and click the participant type, nothing is listed.

I created a participant with the same ID a few hours ago but it has disappeared after I redeployed my changes. Not sure where it went as it clearly hasn't been deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your model by adding/removing fields that are not optional, or by renaming fields, any existing data that does not match the model 'disappears' from view.  However the data is still there and re-appears if you change the model back.

It seems likely that you have changed the model but have residual 'hidden' data and you can't create a new object with the same key you have already used.

This is more fully explained in the [Composer Knowledge Wiki](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-knowledge-wiki/blob/latest/knowledge.md#migration).